# Is there a way to find out how many portlets are there in any page?

Tags: portlet, liferay, portal

The problem is, say, i am having a page `xyz`. And in that page there are 20 portlets. How can i find out the names of all portlets placed on the page.

Provided i am having the admin privilege.

Comment: do you need to know it on your backend-bean or is it enough to know the portlet count on the frontend within JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Liferay the easiest way to do this is probably in the theme, you want to get a hold of the Layout object, that will let you explore the layout and pull references to the portlets on a page.

Some references:

- [http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Layout%20Template#section-Layout+Template-AvailableVariablesInTemplate](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/5.2/javadocs/portal-service/com/liferay/portal/model/Layout.html)
- http://docs.liferay.com/portal/5.2/javadocs/portal-service/com/liferay/portal/model/Layout.html

Answer (score 1):

The two portlet standards (JSR-168 and JSR-286) don't specify any way of finding out the names of the portlets placed on the page.

But, it is possible that each portal provides a proprietary way of achieving what you want to do.